# Is the information in MySQL's performance_schema database stored on disk?

Tags: mysql

I'm somewhat confused about the actual data in this database. The documentation says the performance_schema database is a combination of temporary tables and views. Does that mean this data is held only in memory, or that it's read from a different place on disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema.html says:

> - Tables in the performance_schema database are views or temporary tables that use no persistent on-disk storage.

The performance data is held in volatile RAM only. All the information is discarded if you shut down the mysqld process, and data collection will start over when you restart mysqld.